# Error regarding Component in Debugger, App works

Tags: sapui5

I setup a really simple application from scratch in order to demystify some basics. Just a view at this moment which works, meaning that component works (routing is defined in manifest.json which is called by Component.js) but there's a weird debugger error (see below)

[image: Component error in debugger]

Furthermore, I see Component.js being loaded in the network tab but at a certain point I see an additional attempt (after view has been loaded) to fetch a component that have no idea what is it about (see below)

[image: Debugger network tab]

Looking inside the failed request I see this:

http://localhost:8080/file/uitgka-OrionContent/zouz.sapui5.skeleton/sap/bc/lrep/flex/data/zouz.sapui5.skeleton.Component

This is not my application path, related to something called "Flex Services" which I have no idea what is it about.

Has anybody any idea where this Component exception coming from? Code attached below, seems quite simple.

Thanks in advance,

Greg

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Test_space</title>

    <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
        src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"
        data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
        data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize"
        data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
        data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"          
        data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"zouz.sapui5.skeleton": "../webapp/"}'>
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script>
        sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function() {
            new sap.m.Shell({
                appWidthLimited : false,                    
                app: new sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer({
                    height : "100%",
                    name : "zouz.sapui5.skeleton"
                })
            }).placeAt("content");
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body class="sapUiBody" id="content">
</body>
```

Component.js

```
sap.ui.define([
"sap/ui/core/UIComponent"
], function(UIComponent) {
"use strict";

return UIComponent.extend("zouz.sapui5.skeleton.Component", {

    metadata: {
        manifest: "json"
    },

    /**
     * The component is initialized by UI5 automatically during the startup of the app and calls the init method once.
     * @public
     * @override
     */
    init: function() {
        // call the base component's init function
        UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);
        this.getRouter().initialize();
    }
});
});
```

App.controller.js

```
sap.ui.define([
    "zouz/sapui5/skeleton/controller/BaseController",
    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel"
], function (BaseController, JSONModel) {
    "use strict";

    return BaseController.extend("zouz.sapui5.skeleton.controller.App", {

        onInit : function () {

            var oViewModel,
                fnSetAppNotBusy,
                iOriginalBusyDelay = this.getView().getBusyIndicatorDelay();

            oViewModel = new JSONModel({
                busy : true,
                delay : 0
            });
            this.setModel(oViewModel, "appView");

            fnSetAppNotBusy = function() {
                oViewModel.setProperty("/busy", false);
                oViewModel.setProperty("/delay", iOriginalBusyDelay);
            };

            this.getOwnerComponent().getModel().metadataLoaded().
                then(fnSetAppNotBusy);

            // apply content density mode to root view
            // this.getView().addStyleClass(this.getOwnerComponent().getContentDensityClass()); 

        },
        onBeforeRendering : function() {

        }
    });

}
);
```

Main.controller.js

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"
], function (Controller) {
    "use strict";

    return Controller.extend("zouz.sapui5.skeleton.controller.Main", {

        onInit : function () {

        },
        onBeforeRendering : function() {

        }
    });

}
```

);

App.view.xml

```
<mvc:View
xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
controllerName="zouz.sapui5.skeleton.controller.App"
displayBlock="true"
xmlns="sap.m"
xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">

<App id="app"
     busy="{appView>/busy}"
     busyIndicatorDelay="{appView>/delay}"/>
```

Main.view.xml

```
</mvc:View>

<mvc:View controllerName="zouz.sapui5.skeleton.controller.Main"
xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
xmlns="sap.m"
xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
displayBlock="true">
<App>
    <pages>
        <Page title="Greg test stuff">
            <content id="#contentPlaceholder">
                <Text text="This is view 1"/>
            </content>
        </Page>
    </pages>
</App>
</mvc:View>
```

manifest.json

```
{
"_version": "1.5.0",
"sap.app": {
    "id": "zouz.sapui5.skeleton",
    "type": "application",
    "i18n": "i18n/i18n.properties",
    "applicationVersion": {
        "version": "1.0.0"
    },
    "title": "{{appTitle}}",
    "description": "{{appDescription}}",
    "sourceTemplate": {
        "id": "ui5template.basicSAPUI5ApplicationProject",
        "version": "1.40.12"
    },
    "dataSources": {
        "mainService": {
            "uri": "/DEV/sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZCONTRACTS_SRV/",
            "type": "OData",
            "settings": {
                "odataVersion": "2.0",
                "localUri": "localService/metadata.xml"
            }
        }
    }
},
"sap.ui": {
    "technology": "UI5",
    "icons": {
        "icon": "",
        "favIcon": "",
        "phone": "",
        "phone@2": "",
        "tablet": "",
        "tablet@2": ""
    },
    "deviceTypes": {
        "desktop": true,
        "tablet": true,
        "phone": true
    },
    "supportedThemes": ["sap_hcb", "sap_belize"]
},
"sap.ui5": {
    "rootView": {
        "viewName": "zouz.sapui5.skeleton.view.App",
        "type": "XML"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "minUI5Version": "1.30.0",
        "libs": {
            "sap.ui.core": {},
            "sap.m": {},
            "sap.ui.layout": {},
            "sap.ushell": {},
            "sap.collaboration": {},
            "sap.ui.comp": {},
            "sap.uxap": {}
        }
    },
    "contentDensities": {
        "compact": true,
        "cozy": true
    },
    "models": {
        "i18n": {
            "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
            "settings": {
                "bundleName": "zouz.sapui5.skeleton.i18n.i18n"
            }
        },
        "": {
            "dataSource": "mainService",
            "preload": true,
            "settings": {
                "defaultBindingMode": "TwoWay"
            }
        }
    },
    "routing": {
        "config": {
            "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router",
            "viewType": "XML",
            "viewPath": "zouz.sapui5.skeleton.view",
            "async": true,
            "controlId": "app",             
            "controlAggregation": "pages",
            "bypassed": {
                "target": []
            }
        },
        "routes": [{
            "name": "Main",
            "pattern": "",
            "titleTarget": "",
            "greedy": false,
            "target": ["Main"]
        },
        {
            "name": "Agreement",
            "pattern": "AgreementsSet/{objectId}",
            "titleTarget": "",
            "greedy": false,
            "target": ["Agreement"]
        }],
        "targets": {
            "Main": {
                "viewType": "XML",
                "transition": "slide",
                "clearAggregation": "",
                "viewName": "Main",
                "viewId": "Main",
                "viewLevel": 1
            },
            "Agreement": {
                "viewType": "XML",
                "transition": "slide",
                "clearAggregation": true,
                "viewName": "Agreement",
                "viewLevel": 2,
                "viewId": "Agreement"
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Right now you have two components. Main should probably be a controller, not a UIComponent. `getContentDensityClass` is a function you have to define yourself in the `Component.js`. It is not part of the framework.

Comment: @Marc: Main is a controller, copy paste error, sorry about that, main controller code now in place. Thanks about the function, using only templates, stuck with the idea that this is a part of the framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore those errors.
Both these failures are related to "[Flexibility services](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_uiaddon10/1.17/en-US/a8/e55aa2f8bc4127923b20685a6d1621/content.htm?no_cache=true)". They basically check if the user has any personalization modifications for the component (app).